# SharePoint 2013 List: If you enter specific data into one field, is it possible to auto-populate other fields based off that data?

Tags: 2013, list

If I'm creating a new row, and I type in an Identifier #, is there a way to auto-populate an expiration date column with a date associated with that Identifier #?

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a calculated column? SharePoint allows you to use Excel-like formulas conditionally populate data based on other content in your list item.

[RackSpace Calculated Column Tutorial](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

If the due date is based on a formula related to other information in your list item, or somehow embedded in the identifier #, then a calculated column should work. **But,** if that data lives in another list the calculated column won't be able to reference it.

If that proves to be the case and you need to do a lookup to another app, the easiest option would be to use a SharePoint workflow that automatically runs on item creation/modification and grabs the expiration date with the "update list item" function. [Here's a basic overview](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/workflow/use-update-list-item-action-sharepoint-designer-workflow.htm).